# What is the English term for an all-boys or all-girls school?

Tags: word-choice

Is there any English word referring to a single-sex school (either all-male or all-female schools or colleges)?

Comment: They are most commonly described as *single-sex schools*.

Comment: Also as either a girls school or a boys school.

Comment: non-co-ed for those who like overstating things.